# Different dataset generated on running jupyter notebook every time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a simple classification problem to train my classifier to distinguish between "Clapping" sounds and "Non-clapping" human sounds. For this purpose,I am using the Google AudioSet. In the following code, I am trying to extract audio-embeddings [the youtube video at different instances] and audio-labels["Dancing","Singing",etc].

```
    #To store the features in  a vector
audio_embeddings_dict = {}

#To store the labels
audio_labels_dict = {}

#Load embeddings
sess = tf.Session()
for tfrecord in tfrecord_filenames_non:
    for example in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(tfrecord):
        #To create a new instance from serialized data
        tf_example = tf.train.Example.FromString(example)
        #To store the Youtube Id that we have extracted
        vid_id = tf_example.features.feature['video_id'].bytes_list.value[0].decode(encoding = 'UTF-8')
        if vid_id in non_examples_clapping:
            #Store the labels of the video_id that are present in the examples
            example_label = list(np.asarray(tf_example.features.feature['labels'].int64_list.value))
            #To store the tf_example of only the vid_id that are present in the examples
            tf_seq_example = tf.train.SequenceExample.FromString(example)
            #To store the number of feature vectors present in the audio_embeddings
            n_frames = len(tf_seq_example.feature_lists.feature_list['audio_embedding'].feature)

            #To store the audio_frame in the form of 10 separate vectors each containing 128 examples
            audio_frame = [[]*n_frames for x in range(n_frames)]
            for i in range(n_frames):
                audio_frame[i].append(tf.cast(tf.decode_raw(tf_seq_example.feature_lists.
                feature_list['audio_embedding'].feature[i].bytes_list.value[0],tf.uint8),tf.float32).eval(session = sess))
                audio_embeddings_dict[vid_id] = audio_frame
                audio_labels_dict[vid_id] = example_label
```

I store all the audio-embeddings in 1 dict variable[audio_embeddings_dict]. 
and all the audio_labels_dict.

**Comparison between audio_labels_dict :**

[image]

The complete code can be found here: 
(https://github.com/Anirudh257/Audio-files-extraction/blob/master/Audio%20extraction%20dataset(1).ipynb)

Comment: what exactly are you asking? I've read the question a couple of times and I can't find exactly what you are struggling with

Comment: I want to classify a dataset into "Clapping" and "non-clapping " examples. I am using:(https://research.google.com/audioset/download.html) from Google AudioSet's website. I have tried to extract the different labels associated with the sounds into one dictionary(audio_labels_dict) and all the embeddings(the separation of a sound-clip into 127 feature vectors) into 1 dictionary variable(audio_embeddings_dict). When I try to extract the examples for non_clapping examples, the audio_embeddings and audio_labels get extracted differently on every run of my jupyter notebook.

Comment: Sorry, if I was unclear. I am a newcomer to this website.